# Auto.Arima not returning a difference parameter when it should

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to do a forecast for inflation with arima. When I try to get parameters with auto.arima grid search, using 'oob' as the information criterion, it returns ARIMA(0,0,0),(0,0,0)[12] and a terrible forecast. I also notice that the adf.shoulddiff() returns (0.01, false). yet when I manually set d = 1, I get a far improved if terrible forecast. It seems like it should always return a model with a difference parameter as it performs better when i manually set the difference.

In addition, I'm unsure how to to evaluate my model (with R^2, RMSE which seem highly correlated) or with the forecast confidence interval which tend to be very wide the worse it gets. As i understand it, if the coefficient of terms in the model summary are statistically significant (P < 0.05) the white noise, heteroskedasticity and normality tests are (p> 0.05), i have a good model. is this correct?

Lastly, As of right now, I have decided to use a dateSearch method i created with the params returned to find the best index of my time series (that provides the to determine the training window. Is this correct or are there possible issues with this approach?

See code for auto_arima [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paVkb.png)
``

```
adf_test = ADFTest(alpha=0.05)
diff_bool = adf_test.should_diff(data)

print(adf_test.is_stationary(data))
print(diff_bool)

if (diff_bool[1] == True):
    DIFF_VAL = 1
else:
    DIFF_VAL = None

auto = pm.auto_arima(data, start_p=0, d=DIFF_VAL, start_q=0,
                        test='adf',       # use adftest to find optimal 'd'
                        max_p=3, max_q=3,
                        start_P = 0, start_Q=0,
                        D=DIFF_VAL,
                        max_P = 3,  max_Q = 3,max_D=3,
                        seasonal = True,
                        trace=True, 
                        m=12,             
                        stepwise=True,
                        out_of_sample_size = 12,
                        scoring='mse',
                        information_criterion = 'oob'
                       )
```

Please see below for the model returned in grid search when d= None and the forecast.

```
is_stationary is deprecated and will be removed in a future release of pmdarima. Use should_diff instead.



is_stationary is deprecated and will be removed in a future release of pmdarima. Use should_diff instead.



(0.01, False)(0.01, False)Performing stepwise search to minimize oobARIMA(0,0,0)(0,0,0)[12] intercept   : OOB=98601.134, Time=0.13 secARIMA(1,0,0)(1,0,0)[12] intercept   : OOB=2754.581, Time=0.86 secARIMA(0,0,1)(0,0,1)[12] intercept   : OOB=inf, Time=1.07 secARIMA(0,0,0)(0,0,0)[12]             : OOB=39.040, Time=0.18 secARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,0)[12] intercept   : OOB=59993.182, Time=0.97 secARIMA(0,0,0)(0,0,1)[12] intercept   : OOB=63068.904, Time=0.78 secARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,1)[12] intercept   : OOB=83137.867, Time=1.03 secARIMA(1,0,0)(0,0,0)[12] intercept   : OOB=2804.073, Time=0.26 secARIMA(0,0,1)(0,0,0)[12] intercept   : OOB=inf, Time=0.38 secARIMA(1,0,1)(0,0,0)[12] intercept   : OOB=5196.387, Time=0.87 sec



Best model:  ARIMA(0,0,0)(0,0,0)[12]Total fit time: 6.571 seconds SARIMAX Results


Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                  511Model:                        SARIMAX   Log Likelihood               -4213.127Date:                Tue, 25 Jul 2023   AIC                           8428.255Time:                        20:44:19   BIC                           8432.491Sample:                             0   HQIC                          8429.915- 511Covariance Type:                  opg


             coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]


------------------------------------------------------------------------------


sigma2      8.487e+05   1.52e+04     55.794      0.000    8.19e+05    8.79e+05



Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                 489.93   Jarque-Bera (JB):             12163.76Prob(Q):                              0.00   Prob(JB):                         0.00Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.00   Skew:                             4.40Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.00   Kurtosis:                        25.22
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziN08.png)

When I specify d=1: (assumptiion tests all fail, but the forecast looks more reasonable, and the rmse score as well as r^2 are better).

```
Best model:  ARIMA(0,1,0)(2,0,1)[12] interceptTotal fit time: 50.101 secondsSARIMAX Results



Dep. Variable:                                    y   No. Observations:                  511Model:             SARIMAX(0, 1, 0)x(2, 0, [1], 12)   Log Likelihood               -3385.579Date:                              Tue, 25 Jul 2023   AIC                           6781.158Time:                                      21:18:31   BIC                           6802.330Sample:                                           0   HQIC                          6789.459- 511Covariance Type:                                opg



             coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]


------------------------------------------------------------------------------


intercept     -0.1935     10.069     -0.019      0.985     -19.929      19.542ar.S.L12      -0.0253      0.892     -0.028      0.977      -1.774       1.723ar.S.L24      -0.0425      0.183     -0.232      0.816      -0.401       0.316ma.S.L12      -0.1637      0.893     -0.183      0.854      -1.913       1.586sigma2      3.434e+04    486.079     70.652      0.000    3.34e+04    3.53e+04



Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                 225.86   Jarque-Bera (JB):            186341.93Prob(Q):                              0.00   Prob(JB):                         0.00Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.00   Skew:                             5.47Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.00   Kurtosis:                        96.00
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG46Z.png)

Lastly, I did a seasonal decompose to ensure that there is trend and seassonality and that differencing makes sense.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvDiS.png)